# Does array modifier constant offset use blender units or the object's radius?

Tags: modifiers

From the official guide and some video tutorials I understood that constant offset move in blender units, but when I try to apply it, it works like relative offset but using the radius instead of the whole dimension. In the picture below I used constant offset=1 in all 5 cubes.

[image]

I'm new to blender so I don't know if I misinterpreted the guide, fail to apply it or if it is a bug.

I'm using Blender 2.79 on Linux,Suse Leap 15.1

Comment: @batFINGER has answered this.. this is just putting the same thing another way. The constant offset is in Blender units, _but in the Object Space of the modified object_. If you scale the _object_, (as opposed to scaling its mesh, which you would do by scaling it in Edit Mode) then the object's space is scaled with it.

Comment: That's why it's better to use Relative Offset as it takes the object's size.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth on a case by case basis.  Relative makes it difficult to maintain a Constant offset (and vice versa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Scale is factored in**

The constant offset is in Blender units, *but in the Object Space of the modified object*. If you scale the object, (as opposed to scaling its mesh, which you would do by scaling it in Edit Mode) then the object's space is scaled with it. (Thankyou [@RobinBetts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179720/does-array-modifier-constant-offset-use-blender-units-or-the-objects-radius/179843#comment301105_179720))

So if scale is 2 and constant offset is 1, scaled by 2 is 2 (explaining the result of your "*What I got*" column).

[image]

Image shows default cube with constant offset one array mod.  Notice at unit scale both expected and result are the same.  ***Note***: non unit scale is one of the most common reasons for getting unexpected results in blender

It is then scaled by 2. (Result: "*What I got*")

Finally the scale is applied <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *`Scale`*(sets on local mesh coordinates object scale returns to unity, equiv of edit mode scale or changing radius when creating cube) (Result: "*What I expected*")

To keep scale and maintain the 1 x offset could drive the constant offset by

```
1 / self.id_data.scale.x
```

making sure to check *use self* in driver properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was driving me crazy.

Comment: So that's why has been the `Constant Offset` in Blender always "broken" :-D. Here's my vote up :-)